# Same number of independent parameters for $SO(n)$ and $O(n)$

Tags: group-theory

Why is the number of independent parameters for $SO(n)$ and $O(n)$ same, in spite of an additional constraint of unit determinant for $SO(n)$?

Comment: It seems to me that given some $A\in O(n)$ with determinant $D$, one can always scale using some real number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha A$ has unit determinant, i.e. $\alpha A\in SO(n)$.

Comment: @Danu $\alpha = \pm 1$, so the scaling procedure  you mention is not "continuous" and thus it does not involve a further degree of freedom similar to the remaining parameters of $O(n)$ or $SO(n)$ defined around  the identity...

Comment: Thanks Danu. That is true but I am still wondering how the constraints on the matrix elements for SO do not change by putting unit determinant because SO constraints and O constraints are exactly same.

Comment: @ValterMoretti My point was that you can therefore expect that there is *no* extra parameter, since you can always make an element of $O(n)$ into one of $SO(n)$ (i.e. I think you agree with me)

Comment: Well,I am not sure to agree with you. The point is that if $D$ were continuous a further parameter would take place just to join different values of $D$. But this is not the case since $RR^t=I$ implies $D=\det R = \pm 1$.

Comment: For instance $SU(n)$ and $U(n)$ have a different number of independent parameters, because the determinant of $U\in U(n)$ can attain a continuous set of values.

Comment: @ValterMoretti OK, I see your point. Thanks for clearing this up for me! Perhaps you should consider expanding your comments into an answer.

Comment: I am tired ;), perhaps tomorrow...

Comment: if you dont get an (adequate) answer, you can also post this on math.se or mathoverflow

Comment: the reason [$O(n)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) has same number of parameters to the $SO(n)$ sub-group, is the same reason the permutation group $\Pi(n)$ of $n$ elements and the alternate sub-group of permutations of $n$ ($\Alpha(n)$) have same dimensions

Comment: @Danu Be careful with reasoning on the grounds of some mapping. For example, there exists a mapping $O(n)\to Z_2$, but obviously $O(n)$ does have more parameters for $n>1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: An orthogonal matrix $O^TO={\bf 1}$ must automatically have determinant $\det O = \pm 1$, i.e. the determinant condition does not cut any continuous$^1$ degrees of freedom.

More details:

1. We learn that the set $O(n)$ of orthogonal matrices consists of (at least) two connected components, one with determinant $+1$ and one with determinant $-1$. In fact one may show that $O(n)$ contains precisely 2 connected components.

   - If we look at the component with determinant $+1$, we see that the extra condition $\det O =+1$ for $SO(n)$ is automatically satisfied, and hence do not restrict this component in any way.
   - If we look at the component with determinant $-1$, we see that the extra condition $\det O =+1$ for $SO(n)$ is not satisfied at all, so that the entire component is removed.
   - In conclusion, the component with determinant $+1$ is $SO(n)$.
2. One may show that each of the two components is a real [differential manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold). The dimension is given by the dimension of the corresponding [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra)
   $$o(n)~=~\{ m\in {\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\mid  m^t=-m\},$$ which has dimension $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

--

$^1$ It is interesting to compare with the situation for $U(n)$ and $SU(n)$. Here a unitary matrix $U^{\dagger}U={\bf 1}$ must automatically have determinant $\det U\in U(1)\cong \mathbb{S}^1$ of unit modulus, i.e. the complex determinant (which are now 2 real conditions) condition only cut 1 real degrees of freedom, cf. above comment by V. Moretti.

Comment: i think this should be elaborated a little more, i dont think i get the reason, but i'm not the OP

Comment: I agree. This didn't help me at all

Comment: I updated the answer.